# Missing geometry in ViewData Window in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, pgadmin

Can anyone help me to understand this ambiguity in Postgresql. I have a table of building polygons of large dataset containing 2412785 rows. In PgAdmin-III, when I try to my_table>Right Click>View Data>View all rows, then in the view window it returned some rows with no geometry like this:

[image: Missing geom in View Window]

While at the same time, I tried this command:

```
Select * from my_table;
```

and it returned the geometry values for same rows now like this:

[image: No missing values now]

Can anyone help me to understand this? Does it mean that something wrong went in the import procedure using Postgis shapefile importer or "View Data" is not the recommended way to view large geometries?

Comment: I have seen this before, your geometry data is probably there but is not shown. Maybe this is for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I am of the opinion that "View Data" is not the suitable way to have a look at large geometric datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 95% certain that you are seeing a quirk in pgAdmin III, where it only shows data with a number of characters under a user defined limit. But if the data is greater than that limit a blank cell is shown instead. These blank cells are ambiguous, and you are not the first to be caught by it.

A true test of seeing if the cells are actually `NULL` or not is to use something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE geom IS NULL;
```

Comment: Although, I accepted your feedback as answer but instead of above query (which returned syntax error for me), this command worked fine for me. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE geom IS NULL;